# Show header/footer of Gridview with empty data source?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

How I can show header/footer of Asp.Net Gridview with empty data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read of [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2008/01/30/a-more-elegant-solution-to-display-gridview-header-and-footer-when-the-data-source-is-empty.aspx)

Alternatively, you can define your own custom user interface for the empty data row by using the [EmptyDataTemplate property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx).

Comment: Actually I prefer `EmptyDataTemplate` more than Bind Empty `DataSet` to the `GridView`, I've being doing it and it has a lot of issues and that why they actually put `EmptyDataTemplate`. I was blaming Microsoft for not implement such a feature but to Bind empty DataSet to the GridView is not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this also by assigning one dummy row to the DataSource of the grid.
By default the datasource will be stuffed with the dummy row. So grid will show the footer & dummy row as well.
To hide the row you can add one dummy field for whether to show the control or not. And bind that field to control's Visible property.
Finally when you add the actual row to the datasource... Remove the dummy row you created.

Example - Source:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdQualify" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true"
                        EnableModelValidation="True">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qualifying Exam">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQualifyingExam" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QualifyingExam") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("ShowVisible") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQualifyingExamF" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roll Number">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRollNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RollNumber") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("ShowVisible") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRollNumberF" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Admission Round">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdmissionRound" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AdmissionRound") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("ShowVisible") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdmissionRoundF" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Marks Obtained">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMarksObtained" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MarksObtained") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("ShowVisible") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMarksObtainedF" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Marks Out of">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMarksOutOf" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MarksOutOf") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("ShowVisible") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMarksOutOfF" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Percentage">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPercentage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Percentage") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("ShowVisible") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPercentageF" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Remarks") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("ShowVisible") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarksF" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteQualify" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
                                        Visible='<%# Eval("ShowVisible") %>' onclick="btnDeleteQualify_Click"></asp:Button>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddQualify" runat="server" Text="Add" 
                                        onclick="btnAddQualify_Click"></asp:Button>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Example - Code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            if (ViewState["QualifyDetails"] == null)
                ViewState["QualifyDetails"] = new List<Entity_StudentAcademicQualify>();
            GridDataBindQualify((List<Entity_StudentAcademicQualify>)ViewState["QualifyDetails"]);
        }
    }


    private void GridDataBindQualify(List<Entity_StudentAcademicQualify> list)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            Entity_StudentAcademicQualify studentQualify = new Entity_StudentAcademicQualify();

            studentQualify.ShowVisible = false;
            studentQualify.QualifyingExam = string.Empty;
            studentQualify.RollNumber = string.Empty;
            studentQualify.AdmissionRound = string.Empty;
            studentQualify.MarksObtained = 0;
            studentQualify.MarksOutOf = 0;
            studentQualify.Percentage = 0;
            studentQualify.Remarks = string.Empty;

            list.Add(studentQualify);
        }
        else
        {
            list.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        grdQualify.DataSource = list;
        grdQualify.DataBind();

        ViewState["QualifyDetails"] = list;
    }

    protected void btnAddQualify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Button)sender).Parent.Parent;

        List<Entity_StudentAcademicQualify> studentQualifys =
            (List<Entity_StudentAcademicQualify>)ViewState["QualifyDetails"];

        Entity_StudentAcademicQualify studentQualify = new Entity_StudentAcademicQualify();

        studentQualify.ShowVisible = true;
        studentQualify.QualifyingExam = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtQualifyingExamF")).Text;
        studentQualify.RollNumber = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtRollNumberF")).Text;
        studentQualify.AdmissionRound = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtAdmissionRoundF")).Text;
        studentQualify.MarksObtained = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtMarksObtainedF")).Text);
        studentQualify.MarksOutOf = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtMarksOutOfF")).Text);
        studentQualify.Percentage = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtPercentageF")).Text);
        studentQualify.Remarks = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtRemarksF")).Text;

        studentQualifys.Add(studentQualify);

        GridDataBindQualify(studentQualifys);
    }

    protected void btnDeleteQualify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Entity_StudentAcademicQualify> studentQualifys =
          (List<Entity_StudentAcademicQualify>)ViewState["QualifyDetails"];

        studentQualifys.RemoveAt(((GridViewRow)((Button)sender).Parent.Parent).RowIndex);

        GridDataBindQualify(studentQualifys);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I read a lot of posts online about this and at the end of it I came up with my own solution that addresses my needs, and hopefully the needs of others, including this question.

The need to show header/footer may be because 
1) I want the user to see the structure of the grid, and 
2) I want to use the footer to add new data to the table.

Therefore, simply showing 'no data available' is not sufficient.

So my solution is test if data is available. If not, then create the structure of the datasource and populate one row's required fields with default values. This is important because if you bind a datasource to the grid when fields like boolean and dates are empty you will have 'DBNull' errors. Then bind this new datasource to the grid. then hide the row, in this sequence.

```
Protected Sub BindGrid()
    con = New SqlConnection("mainLocal")
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Test", con)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)

    dim rows as integer = dt.Rows.Count
    If rows = 0 Then
        Dim dr As DataRow = Nothing

        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("isActive") = False
        dr("Dated") = Date.Now()
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    End If

    Me.TestGridView.DataSource = dt
    Me.TestGridView.DataBind()
    If rows = 0 Then Me.TestGridView.Rows(0).Visible = False
End Sub
```

I guess much simpler, shorter, neater!